# Stripe, Cancel subscription with PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to cancel a stripe subscription using PHP at the end of the current period but cannot find any examples of the version I use nor in the documentation.

My code is as follows

```
$stripe->subscriptions->cancel(
   $subscription_id,
   [
      'invoice_now' => true,
      'cancel_at_period_end' => true
   ]
);
```

However, this doesn't work and I cannot find how to set the subscription to end at the end of the period.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass the [`cancel_at_period_end` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-cancel_at_period_end) when calling the [subscription cancel](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel) endpoint. Instead the subscription will be cancelled **immediately**.

Instead you should call the [subscription update](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) endpoint and pass the associated parameters:

```php
$stripe->subscriptions->update(
   $subscription_id,
   [
      'cancel_at_period_end' => true
   ]
);
```

Comment: Awesome, make sense and it works. :) Thanks.

Comment: fantastic! thankyou - maybe helpful for others - you can also check if a subscription is still active but has been cancelled by looking at the 'canceled_at' property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel the subscription immediately you have to use this cancel API:

```
$stripe->subscriptions->cancel($subscription_id, []);
```

If you want to cancel the subscription at the end of the billing period then you have to use update API:

```
$stripe->subscriptions->update($subscription_id, ['cancel_at_period_end' => true]);
```